# Group Box in different Thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have 5 Group Box in my software I want to run them differently for example I have one group box which takes lot of time around 20-30 minutes till then my software hangs. SO I want to make other functionality working when a particular group box is working any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Group boxes don't "work". If they're just some GUI for a resource intensive task, you probably want to run that task asynchronously (or multi-threaded, depending on your requirements) and only use the GUI for settings / updates / whatever. The key is to never do much work on the GUI thread - if a GUI action takes more than say 50-100ms, it should probably be done elsewhere. Note that using `await` makes this very easy to do properly - if that's not available, a `BackgroundWorker` is probably the best option. Do note it doesn't shield you from synchronization issues, though!

Comment: Can u give me a suggestion I have a task which send messages, after every message I call Thread.Sleep(5000). There is a log file which keep trace on this so I need to manipulate log file mean while or cancel the sending message task so what should I exactly use for send button

Comment: @Kirtesh `BackgroundWorker` can handle all those. The simplest way to rewrite your code would be to start the background worker in your send button - the background worker can check for cancellation, post progress to GUI, whatever. A better way would be to use `await Task.Delay(5000)` instead, for example - since you're waiting anyway, there's no need to waste a thread for doing that. There's very few rare use cases for `Thread.Sleep` aside from debugging, and this isn't a good use case :)

Comment: Will BackgroundWorker will work if my send button calls too many classes from it as I am working with whatsappapi The send button calls a lot of classes when it runs

Comment: @Kirtesh There's no reason why the send button has to do that - just let the send button run the background worker that actually calls the API method in turn. Or if the API is asynchronous, just use `await` - it's obvious that there's no CPU work involved, just I/O.